# Get dynamically-created html div with Coded UI

Tags: javascript, html, dom, coded-ui-tests

I need to verify if some errors are handled on my page.

Errors trigger a javascript popup which is a div element.

This popup is dynamically generated, and I don't know how to check if this appears with my Coded UI test.

I wrote this code, but this test pass every time, whether popup is displayed or not

```
[...]
HtmlDiv ErrorPopup = new HtmlDiv(document);
ErrorPopup.FilterProperties["name"] = "ErrorDialog";

[some actions that will lead to error]
Assert.IsTrue(ErrorPopup.Exists,"Popup not displayed");
```

With no error, there's no popup code in page source.

How to check it?

Comment: Why don't you just use the recorder to add the assertion?

Comment: I tried, but the assertion is strictly tied to popup error content, which is not always the same

Comment: Then assert the error div exists property first, then assert the content text. (tho by your original post you are only trying to assert the existence of the error div)

Comment: Try `ErrorPopup.TryFind()`.
To dig these kinds of problem I would properly debug though. Put a breakpoint on assert and check ErrorPopup's properties. Try doing `ErrorPopup.DrawHighlight()` in debug and see if it actually highlights anything on page.

Comment: My guess would be that since you only set a filter property and no search property it will get the first HtmlDiv it can find if the popup is not there. Try `ErrorPopup.SearchProperties["name"] = "ErrorDialog"`.